# Querying with multiple predicates on sub-objects in a collection with MongoDB (official c# driver)

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I've the following data structure:

- A

  - _id
  - B[]

    - _id
    - C[]

      - _id
      - UserId

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
where a.B._id == 'some-id' and a.B.C.UserId=='some-user-id'.
```

That means I need to find a B document that has a C document within with the relevant UserId, something like:

```
Query.And(Query.EQ("B._id", id), Query.EQ("B.C.UserId", userId));
```

This is not good, of course, as it may find B with that id and another different B that has C with that UserId. Not good.

How can I write it with the official driver?

Comment: I had some trouble understanding your document structure, maybe you could format it better? 
Also, now that I understand what you're asking for (I hope), I think you should use a different title: your question isn't about how to reach into 3rd-level objects, but rather how to apply complex predicates to a single sub-document in a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is only that your two predicates on B are evaluated on different B instances ("it may find B with that ID and another different B that has C with that UserId"), then the solution is to use an operator that says "find me an item in the collection that satisfies *both* these predicates together".

Seems like the [$elemMatch operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch) does exactly that.
From the docs:

> Use $elemMatch to check if an element in an array matches the specified match expression. [...]
>   Note that a single array element must
>   match all the criteria specified; [...]
>   You only need to use this when more than 1 field must be matched in the array element.

Try this:

```
Query.ElemMatch("B", Query.And(
  Query.EQ("_id", id),
  Query.EQ("C.UserId", userId)
));
```

Here's a good explanation of [$elemMatch and dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-Matchingwith%24elemMatch), which matches this scenario exactly.

Comment: Happy to help. I actually learned about this in the process of writing the answer, so thank you :)